# Unable to call Apple Push Notification service (APNS) through web service(php API). Here APNS service is called via proxy server?

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

Unable to call Apple Push Notification service (APNS) through web service(php API). Here APNS service is called via proxy server. I am making APNS call in web service(php API). Here APNS service is called via proxy server. Because i can't make direct connection with apple server. We have restriction that can't able to connect other server/ URI directly from our live server. So, i have only possible to call other servers with the help of proxy.
    I'm getting the below error message while calling the web service,

```
Please find the error message to the API call.

stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

Please provide perfect solution to this issue.
```

Comment: try this question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/14563097/1868660