# Apple APNS - how many push should be sent from server in a second

Tags: java, php, ios, apple-push-notifications

We have large number of users for a game and we have written our own PHP server for sending push tokens. Now when we send push from server then server sends Push to all devices and shows no error. But over device, push is not received.

We tried to send to single device from the server with same application certificate then it worked fine. But when we send it to all devices then push was not recieved. Is there any limit imposed by Apple on number of push in 1 second OR is there any other suggestion which we can follow to send push to large number of devices in parallel?

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/q/14563097/1868660

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have changed implementation from PHP to Java APNS provided by google code and its work perfectly fine for thousands of devices. Tested for 20K devices and works like charm. Following is the link of google code : code.google.com/p/javapns

Answer (score 1):

The limit applies only if you send multiple notifications to the same device

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG23

You wrote that one notifications to one device is received, when you try to send to all the devices nothing is received. What about 2 notifications to 2 devices?

I suspect that there's something wrong with your php and handling more than one device token. Don't reinvent the wheel. http://www.easyapns.com/

If you are using a custom code that can't be replaced I would suggest reading the easyapns php code and try to figure out what you did wrong.

Comment: I was searching more over it and found following:   rule of thumb is no more than 15 simultaneous connections. No need to spread them out to other servers yourself -- just let the round-robin DNS handle that.

Comment: Reference link for discussion is:
http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/57520-performance-push-notification-service.html

Does this make sense?

Comment: There's no valid source for this except someone that wrote "When I've talked with Apple engineers". I'll stick to my answer above :)

Comment: Its not about whose answer is valid or not. I am not even arguing that your answer is not correct. 
My original question is to check number of connections should be made for 1 message to send it to multiple devices at any given time.

Comment: Like I said above, There are a lot of apps in the Appstore that does the exact same thing with no problem at all. Your problem is not related to the APNS limitations.

Comment: We have changed implementation from PHP to Java APNS provided by google code and its work perfectly fine for thousands of devices. Tested for 20K devices and works like charm.

Following is the link of google code :
http://code.google.com/p/javapns/