# How to send push notification to ios device from a php apache server?

Tags: php, ios, curl, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am new to push notification. I want to send push notification from a php-apache server to IOS device.I have the following:

1.pem certificate
2.device id
3.password

My server is an ordinary http server. can I send using http?? My 443 port is disabled. Please give some php working codes to send push notification based on these.

Comment: Hello, your question doesn't show what you have tried or if you have done any research. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Refer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563097/sending-multiple-iphone-push-notifications-apns-php-tutorial). hope it helps